# Не входит в цикл while, объясните почему

Tags: python-3.6

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
i = 0

def nod(n,m):
    while (n != 0) and (m != 0):
        if n > m:
            n = n % m
        else:
            m = m % n
    return(n + m)

while a < c and b < d:
    a += 1
    b += 1
    i += 1
    if a == c and b == d:
        break
    a = a / nod(a,b)
    b = b / nod(a,b)
```

Comment: Наверное, потому что условие "a < c and b < d" не выполняется?

Comment: самый простой способ отладки - добавление принтов, `print(a < c and b < d)` перед `while` что выдает?

Comment: да и правда, вместо  a < c нужно было написать a <= c. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Потому что,  вместо `a < c` нужно было написать `a <= c`